# Restarting Android device, restarts twice on FCM notification receive

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) in my android mobile app. I want to restart the android device(rooted) when a notification is received to device through FCM. But when I restart the device using following code, the device restarts and again it restarts automatically(though I didn't send the notification). Why this happens? How can I solve this?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "reboot now"});
```

I send POST request to  [https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send](http://%20https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) url as mentioed in **right** answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase) question.

My Code is as follows

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
            String restart = "restart";
            String take_screenshot = "take_Screenshot";

            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
                Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
                final String myCustomKey = data.get("my_custom_key");
                reboot();
            }
            private void reboot() {
                try {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "reboot now"});
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Please post your stack trace for better debugging of this issue.

Comment: IMHO, it's ***bad user experience*** to trigger a device restart with a push notification.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that restarting the device too quickly doesn't allow FCM to store the information that it received the message.

Therefore when the device restart the message is downloaded (and delivered to the app again).

I suggest to add few seconds of delay before the reboot.

Comment: I tried that. That didn't work. This happens only in some devices(KitKat). It works fine in a Lolipop device.

Comment: Could you check you have the latest version of Google Play services apk ?

Comment: also, is the linux command "sync" available in the console? if yes try to call it before invoking reboot, it might help to write the data to the filesystem.

Comment: Ok I'll check. Thanx @Diego Giorgini